# How can I draw letters in turtle at the same time?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I wrote a turtle code which writes my name - letter by letter
I want turtle to write the letters at the same time but I dont know how
Can someone help? Would it be possible to define the letters and then store them in a list and then put the list in a print function to draw the letter silmutaneously?
here is the code:

```
import turtle
beni=turtle.Screen()
beni=turtle.Turtle()
beni.speed(4)
beni.pensize(20)
beni.pencolor('dark turquoise')
beni.penup()
beni.setx(-250)
beni.pendown()

beni.left(90)
beni.forward(200)
beni.right(90)
beni.forward(50)
for i in range (36):
    beni.right(5)
    beni.forward(5)
beni.forward(45)
beni.right(90)
beni.right(90)
beni.forward(50)
for i in range (36):
    beni.right(5)
    beni.forward(5)
beni.forward(45)
beni.right(90)
beni.forward(200)
beni.right(180)
beni.forward(200)

beni.penup()
beni.left(90)
beni.forward(150)
beni.pendown()
beni.left(90)

beni.pencolor('light blue')
beni.forward(220)
beni.right(90)
beni.forward(100)
beni.penup()
beni.left(180)
beni.forward(100)
beni.left(90)
beni.forward(110)
beni.left(90)
beni.pendown()
beni.forward(100)
beni.penup()
beni.left(180)
beni.forward(100)
beni.left(90)
beni.forward(110)
beni.left(90)
beni.pendown()
beni.forward(100)

beni.penup()
beni.forward(50)
beni.pendown()
beni.left(90)

beni.pencolor('plum')
beni.forward(220)
beni.right(90)
beni.right(70)
beni.forward(235)
beni.left(70)
beni.left(90)
beni.forward(220)

beni.penup()
beni.right(180)
beni.forward(220)
beni.left(90)
beni.forward(50)
beni.left(90)
beni.pendown()

beni.pencolor('Pale Green')
beni.forward(220)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by its nature it can't draw more than one thing at exactly the same
>   time

You should know better than say ***can't*** when it comes to turtles.  Crude but functional:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_b(t):
    t.begin_poly()
    t.forward(220)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(50)

    for _ in range(36):
        t.right(5)
        t.forward(5)

    t.forward(45)
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(50)

    for _ in range(36):
        t.right(5)
        t.forward(5)

    t.forward(45)
    t.end_poly()

    return t.get_poly()

def draw_e(t):
    t.begin_poly()
    t.forward(220)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.backward(100)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(110)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.backward(100)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(110)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.end_poly()

    return t.get_poly()

def draw_n(t):
    t.begin_poly()
    t.forward(220)
    t.right(160)
    t.forward(235)
    t.left(160)
    t.forward(220)
    t.end_poly()

    return t.get_poly()

def draw_i(t):
    t.begin_poly()
    t.forward(220)
    t.backward(220)
    t.end_poly()

    return t.get_poly()

def draw_polygon(turtle, polygon):
    head, *tail = polygon

    turtle.goto(head)
    turtle.pendown()

    if tail:
        screen.ontimer(lambda p=tail: draw_polygon(turtle, p), 75)
    else:
        turtle.hideturtle()

LETTERS = {
    'B': ('dark turquoise', draw_b, 'fastest'),
    'E': ('light blue', draw_e, 'slowest'),
    'I': ('pale green', draw_i, 'fast'),
    'N': ('plum', draw_n, 'slow'),
}

screen = Screen()

for i, letter in enumerate("BENI"):
    color, function, speed = LETTERS[letter]

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.setx(-250 + 150 * i)

    polygon = function(turtle)

    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.pensize(20)
    turtle.speed(speed)
    turtle.showturtle()

    draw_polygon(turtle, polygon)

screen.mainloop()
```

We follow @SamStafford's great advice about making individual letters into functions.  But rather than have the functions print the letters, we have them draw the letter invisibly and return the resulting polygon.  We walk all the polygons in parallel (simulated with `ontimer()`) finally drawing the letters.

To facilitate this, I've modified the drawing code not to lift the pen.  This wasn't much of an issue as most of the pen up draw was overdrawing existing lines.

Answer (score 0):

The entire idea of a turtle is that it just draws a line wherever it goes, so by its nature it can't draw more than one thing at exactly the same time.  You could define functions for your letters, though, like this:

```
import turtle

def draw_b(t: Turtle):
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(200)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(50)
    for i in range (36):
        t.right(5)
        t.forward(5)
    t.forward(45)
    t.right(90)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(50)
    for i in range (36):
        t.right(5)
        t.forward(5)
    t.forward(45)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(200)
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(200)

    t.penup()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(150)
    t.pendown()
    t.left(90)

def draw_e(t: Turtle):
    t.forward(220)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.penup()
    t.left(180)
    t.forward(100)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(110)
    t.left(90)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(100)
    t.penup()
    t.left(180)
    t.forward(100)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(110)
    t.left(90)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(100)

    t.penup()
    t.forward(50)
    t.pendown()
    t.left(90)

def draw_n(t:Turtle):
    t.forward(220)
    t.right(90)
    t.right(70)
    t.forward(235)
    t.left(70)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(220)

    t.penup()
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(220)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(50)
    t.left(90)
    t.pendown()

def draw_i(t: Turtle):
    t.forward(220)
    t.backward(220)
    t.penup()
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(50)
    t.left(90)
    t.pendown()

turtle.Screen()
beni=turtle.Turtle()
beni.speed(4)
beni.pensize(20)
beni.penup()
beni.setx(-250)
beni.pendown()

beni.pencolor('dark turquoise')
draw_b(beni)
beni.pencolor('light blue')
draw_e(beni)
beni.pencolor('plum')
draw_n(beni)
beni.pencolor('Pale Green')
draw_i(beni)
```